# How to make the Objective-C generic work with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Tried to play the Objective-C generic and implemented a Queue.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Queue<T> : NSObject

@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) T _Nullable front;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) T _Nullable back;

- (_Nullable T) dequeue;
- (Queue * _Nonnull) enqueue:(T)item;
- (BOOL) isEmpty;

@end
```

and create a Queue instance in Swift

```
let queue: Queue<String> = Queue()
```

got error of **Queue' requires that 'String' be a class type** since String is a struct in swift.

I would appreciate any suggestion to make the Objective-C generic work on Swift.

Comment: I'm afraid that you could treat `Generic`s the same way for **Objective-C** & **Swift** both. Something like that you can't use **Swift** struct in **Objective-C**.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use and cast `String` to `NSString`.
I mean, use `let queue: Queue<NSString> = Queue()` instead.
For use a proxy class like this:

```
class Container {
var value: String = ""
}
```

`T` has to be only an `NSObject`. For Swift-ObjC binding only `class` types can be used for bridging. Just hide your value inside another class class (`Container`).

The other case – using ObjC protocol instead of T

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)someMessage;
@end

@interface Queue: NSObject

@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) SomeProtocol _Nullable front;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) SomeProtocol _Nullable back;

- (_Nullable SomeProtocol) dequeue;
- (Queue * _Nonnull) enqueue:(SomeProtocol)item;
- (BOOL) isEmpty;

@end
```

in Swift code you can use `let someProtocolObject: SomeProtocol?`

Comment: hi Vyacheslav, thanks for your prompt response. The plan is to create a standalone framework for Swift app. So I would like to make it transparent and the client doesn't need to cast/use NSString.

So they can just create an instance like let queue = Queue<String>()

Comment: So, use container class wrapper, or `protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject`, but this is not a generic case

Comment: Hi Vyacheslav, could you please explain your suggestions in detail?